# What is the etymology of the term “特定厨”?

Tags: etymology

For those of you who have never heard of the term “特定厨”, please allow me to explain.

According to [Weblio](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%89%B9%E5%AE%9A%E5%8E%A8), there are two definitions:

> 1. person who identifies someone's private information (esp. through online research); doxxer; doxer; Internet sleuth
> 2. person who identifies real-life locations or items appearing in anime, video games, etc.

There is an interesting answer on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-use-of-their-real-names-not-popular-amongst-Japanese-Internet-users) that makes comments about “特定厨”. The comments are as follows.

> Also, there are people called Tokuteichu (特定厨) in the 2chan community. They specialize in identifying the identity of people just by reading their posts or seeing photographs. They have existed since the early 2000’s but significantly grew after the HaseKara calamity. Tokuteichu’s capability is notorious and even the police had their spine chilled after many cases where Tokuteichu discovered who they were looking for in a fraction of time the police took. When they target someone or show interest in them, that person is finished, and their interests are unpredictable. Often they go after wanted criminals or people who post provocative posts online, however, they sometimes go after people who are having a better life than themselves, people who stick out from the rest, people who they consider disrupting the order of society, and both people who are physically unattractive or physically attractive.
>
> It is said that there can be as many as half a million people who are Tokuteichu in Japan. Many of them are said to be unemployed, but the majority are ordinary citizens with various backgrounds. These are people you do not want to antagonize. They are the modern Gestapo of Japan.

And I thought that one group Anonymous was scary! (Shudder) But I digress.

Is there anyone here who knows the etymology of the term “特定厨”? I would really appreciate your answers.